# Rust: error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `&`-pointer `*strm` as mutable

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've run up against the borrow checker again...

```
enum TcpOrStr {
     AddTcp(TcpStream),
     RmTcp(SocketAddr),
     Str(String, SocketAddr)
}

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 5555);

    // bind the listener to the specified address
    let mut acceptor = listener.listen();

    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    spawn(proc() {
        let mut streams: Vec<TcpStream> = Vec::new();
        loop {
            let rxd: TcpOrStr = rx.recv();
            match rxd {
                AddTcp(stream) => {
                    streams.push(stream);
                }
                RmTcp(src) => {
                    // FIXME: O(n) operation
                    streams.retain(|mut strm|{ return strm.peer_name().unwrap() != src});
                }
                Str(line, src) => {
                    for stream in streams.iter_mut() {
                        if stream.peer_name().unwrap() == src {
                            continue;
                        }
                        let mut line_vec = line.clone().into_bytes();
                        let _ = stream.write(line_vec.as_mut_slice());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The error is:

```
   Compiling chat v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/rust/chat)
src/chat.rs:29:55: 29:59 error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `&`-pointer `*strm` as mutable
src/chat.rs:29                     streams.retain(|mut strm|{ return strm.peer_name().unwrap() != src});
                                                                     ^~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `chat`.
```

What's my mistake here?

Comment: Suggestion: HashMap<peer_name, TcpStream>.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Thanks, I was just looking at the `TreeSet` docs (with `<SocketAddr, TcpStream>`).  Is `HashMap`/`HashSet` more suitable?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Don't worry, http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/ explains it all.  I had looked for `HashMap`, but I hadn't been able to find it for some reason (hence `TreeMap`/`TreeSet`) (until I tried the site-search a minute ago).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument passed to the predicate in `retain` is never mutable, but `peer_name()` can only be called on a mutable object.

Not sure what the best solution is there.

http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/net/tcp/struct.TcpStream.html#method.peer_name

http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain